# Open http web (apache) folder as a regular directory

Tags: apache2, nautilus, directory, browser

I've just had a thought - how could I open (without WebDav) a

http://example.com/my_files

I though nautilus would handle this the same way it works with ftp://something - but I was wrong...

Any suggestions or other program that would allow to browse the content (just view + copy files).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, because it's the web server that has to be configured to serve directory indexes.  If you control the webserver, you can activate that with `Options Indexes` in your Apache configuration.  (Other webservers surely have similar configuration options).  Even then, you could only use that while using your browser.

What you want is actually pretty much what WebDAV does.  However, for WebDAV too, you need access to the server configuration.

Comment: It does have 'Option Indexes'

<Directory "/mnt/files">
    Options +Indexes
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
    </IfModule>

    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: Make sure you don't have `index.html`  or `index.htm` in the `/mnt/files`.  Because of the `DirectoryIndex` directive, you'll get those loaded if you do not specify a filename.  That, or comment out the `DirectoryIndex` directive.  Once you have done either one, you will be able to browse your files using a browser (but only a browser - I tested with Nautilus, and it won't accept a pure directory if it doesn't react to the WebDAV extentions)

Comment: true, I have the same observation. Nautilus should be able to present that easily :/